# VBA to remove Password to Open Word Documents

Tags: vba, ms-word, passwords

I teach and during exams I provide students with some materials they can use on the exams digitally in a folder.  The lesson plans, which they are not allowed to use, are also in that same folder.  I am trying to write VBA code to lock up to 10 lesson plans (word documents) just prior to the examination and then a second sub to unlock those same 10 lesson plans after the exam.  My lesson plan folders and names change periodically, so I defined them in their own "VSet" Sub.  The PWLock sub locks all of the documents with the selected password.  However, PWUnlock will not remove that "password to open" password.  I have tried a couple different ways to save the documents without a password, but haven't been able to succeed.  No matter what I try, once the password is set by the PWLock, I can't remove it with my VBA, but can remove it if I open the document and then delete the password when saving the document manually.  Thank you in advance for your time and consideration.  Here is my code -

````
    Dim ComPath, LP1Path, LP2Path, LP3Path, LP4Path, LP5Path, LP6Path, LP7Path, LP8Path, LP9Path, LP10Path As String
    Dim LP1Folder, LP2Folder, LP3Folder, LP4Folder, LP5Folder, LP6Folder, LP7Folder, LP8Folder, LP9Folder, LP10Folder As String
    Dim LP1, LP2, LP3, LP4, LP5, LP6, LP7, LP8, LP9, LP10 As String
    Public Const strPassword As String = "password"
    Public Const noPassword As String = ""
        
Sub VSet() 'Used as a single place to set the variables for use in the PWLock and PWUnlock Subs so they can be easily changed for each teaching cycle
    
    ComPath = "K:\FOLDER\FOLDER\FOLDER\TEST\"'Change this path as needed to main folder for cycle
    'Folders are the individual folders for each class - change as needed - comment out unneeded folders
    LP1Folder = "Class 1\"
    LP2Folder = "Class 2\"
    LP3Folder = "Class 3\"
    LP4Folder = "Class 4\"
    LP5Folder = "Class 5\"
    LP6Folder = "Class 6\"
    LP7Folder = "Class 7\"
    LP8Folder = "Class 8\"
    LP9Folder = "Class 9\"
    LP10Folder = "Class 10\"
    'Lesson plan file names with extenstions - change as needed - comment out unneeded file names
    LP1 = "Class 1 LP.docx"
    LP2 = "Class 2 LP.docx"
    LP3 = "Class 3 LP.docx"
    LP4 = "Class 4 LP.docx."
    LP5 = "Class 5 LP.docx."
    LP6 = "Class 6 LP.docx"
    LP7 = "Class 7 LP.docx"
    LP8 = "Class 8 LP.docx"
    LP9 = "Class 9 LP.docx"
    LP10 = "Class 10 LP.docx"
'Paths to open and save documents - should not need to be changed - comment out unneeded paths
    LP1Path = ComPath & LP1Folder & LP1
    LP2Path = ComPath & LP2Folder & LP2
    LP3Path = ComPath & LP3Folder & LP3
    LP4Path = ComPath & LP4Folder & LP4
    LP5Path = ComPath & LP5Folder & LP5
    LP6Path = ComPath & LP6Folder & LP6
    LP7Path = ComPath & LP7Folder & LP7
    LP8Path = ComPath & LP8Folder & LP8
    LP9Path = ComPath & LP9Folder & LP9
    LP10Path = ComPath & LP10Folder & LP10
End Sub
 
 Sub PWLock()
 
    VSet

    'LP1 - lesson plan
    Documents.Open FileName:=LP1Path
    With ActiveDocument
        .Password = strPassword
        .SaveAs FileName:=LP1Path, Password:=strPassword
        ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges
    End With
    'LP2 - lesson plan
    Documents.Open FileName:=LP2Path
    With ActiveDocument
        .Password = strPassword
        .SaveAs FileName:=LP2Path, Password:=strPassword
        ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges
    End With
   'LP3 - lesson plan
    Documents.Open FileName:=LP3Path
    With ActiveDocument
        .Password = strPassword
        .SaveAs FileName:=LP3Path, Password:=strPassword
        ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges
    End With
   'LP4 - lesson plan
    Documents.Open FileName:=LP4Path
    With ActiveDocument
        .Password = strPassword
        .SaveAs FileName:=LP4Path, Password:=strPassword
        ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges
    End With
   'LP5 lesson plan
    Documents.Open FileName:=LP5Path
    With ActiveDocument
        .Password = strPassword
        .SaveAs FileName:=LP5Path, Password:=strPassword
        ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges
    End With
   'LP6 - lesson plan
    Documents.Open FileName:=LP6Path
    With ActiveDocument
        .Password = strPassword
        .SaveAs FileName:=LP6Path, Password:=strPassword
        ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges
    End With
    'LP7 - lesson plan
'    Documents.Open FileName:=LP7Path
'    With ActiveDocument
'        .Password = strPassword
'        .SaveAs FileName:=LP7Path, Password:=strPassword
'        ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges
'    End With
    'LP8 - lesson plan
'    Documents.Open FileName:=LP8Path
'    With ActiveDocument
'        .Password = strPassword
'        .SaveAs FileName:=LP8Path, Password:=strPassword
'        ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges
'    End With
    'LP9 - lesson plan
'    Documents.Open FileName:=LP9Path
'    With ActiveDocument
'        .Password = strPassword
'        .SaveAs FileName:=LP9Path, Password:=strPassword
'        ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges
'    End With
    'LP10 - lesson plan
'    Documents.Open FileName:=LP10Path
'    With ActiveDocument
'        .Password = strPassword
'        .SaveAs FileName:=LP10Path, Password:=strPassword
'        ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges
'    End With
CloseAll
End Sub

Sub PWUnlock()

    VSet

    'LP1 - lesson plan
    Documents.Open FileName:=LP1Path, PasswordDocument:=strPassword
    With ActiveDocument
        .Password = noPassword
        .SaveAs FileName:=LP1Path, Password:=noPassword
        ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges
    End With
    'LP2 - lesson plan
    Documents.Open FileName:=LP2Path, PasswordDocument:=strPassword
    With ActiveDocument
        .Password = noPassword
        .SaveAs FileName:=LP2Path, Password:=noPassword
        ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges
    End With
    'LP3 - lesson plan
    Documents.Open FileName:=LP3Path, PasswordDocument:=strPassword
    With ActiveDocument
        .Password = noPassword
        .SaveAs FileName:=LP3Path, Password:=noPassword
        ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges
    End With
    'LP4 - lesson plan
    Documents.Open FileName:=LP4Path, PasswordDocument:=strPassword
    With ActiveDocument
        .Password = noPassword
        .SaveAs FileName:=LP4Path, Password:=noPassword
        ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges
    End With
    'LP5 - lesson plan
    Documents.Open FileName:=LP5Path, PasswordDocument:=strPassword
    With ActiveDocument
        .Password = noPassword
        .SaveAs FileName:=LP5Path, Password:=noPassword
        ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges
    End With
    'LP6 - lesson plan
    Documents.Open FileName:=LP6Path, PasswordDocument:=strPassword
    With ActiveDocument
        .Password = noPassword
        .SaveAs FileName:=LP6Path, Password:=noPassword
        ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges
    End With
'    'LP7 - lesson plan
'    Documents.Open FileName:=LP7Path, PasswordDocument:=strPassword
'    With ActiveDocument
'        .Password = noPassword
'        .SaveAs FileName:=LP7Path, Password:=noPassword
'        ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges
'    End With
'    'LP8 - lesson plan
'    Documents.Open FileName:=LP8Path, PasswordDocument:=strPassword
'    With ActiveDocument
'        .Password = noPassword
'        .SaveAs FileName:=LP8Path, Password:=noPassword
'        ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges
'    End With
'    'LP9 - lesson plan
'    Documents.Open FileName:=LP9Path, PasswordDocument:=strPassword
'    With ActiveDocument
'        .Password = noPassword
'        .SaveAs FileName:=LP9Path, Password:=noPassword
'        ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges
'    End With
'    'LP10 - lesson plan
'    Documents.Open FileName:=LP10Path, PasswordDocument:=strPassword
'    With ActiveDocument
'        .Password = noPassword
'        .SaveAs FileName:=LP10Path, Password:=noPassword
'        ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges
'    End With
End Sub

Sub CloseAll()
     'Close all open files and shutdown Word
     
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
         
         'Loop Through open documents
        Do Until .Documents.Count = 0
             'Close saving changes
            .Documents(1).Close SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges
        Loop
         
         'Quit Word no save
        .Quit SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges
    End With
End Sub```
````

Comment: When declaring variables in VBA it is necessary to assign the datatype individually. With `Dim ComPath, LP1Path, ... LP10Path As String` only the last variable is a string the others inherit the default datatype of variant. The correct syntax is `Dim ComPath as String, LP1Path as String, ... LP10Path As String

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's the reason behind it but you need to save the file as a different name after removing the password for it to take effect.

Your code are basically repeating the same action for each document so it's advisable to make it into a sub so that it is easier to maintain and read. For that, I have make locking and unlocking of document into a Sub, `LockDocument` and `UnlockDocument` respectively.

As you are also providing the file name manually, this could lead into a situation where you have a typo and the file does not actually exist so I have also added a check before locking/unlocking to see if the file exist first before it continue.

As you can see, now your `PWLock` and `PWUnlock` sub have effectively reduced into just calling the sub with the file path.

```
Sub PWLock()
    VSet
    
    LockDocument LP1Path
    LockDocument LP2Path
    LockDocument LP3Path
End Sub

Sub PWUnlock()
    VSet
    
    UnlockDocument LP1Path
    UnlockDocument LP2Path
    UnlockDocument LP3Path
End Sub

Sub LockDocument(argPath As String)
'Lock the document with the given path name
    
    If Dir(argPath) <> vbNullString Then    'Check if the file exist before proceeding to lock
        Dim lockDoc As Document
        Set lockDoc = Application.Documents.Open(FileName:=argPath, Visible:=False)
        
        With lockDoc
            .Password = strPassword
            .SaveAs FileName:=argPath, Password:=strPassword
            .Close SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges
        End With
        
        Set lockDoc = Nothing
    Else
        'Error - File not found
        MsgBox "Error - File not exist: " & vbNewLine & _
                argPath
    End If
End Sub


Sub UnlockDocument(argPath As String)
'Unlock the document with the given path name
    
    If Dir(argPath) <> vbNullString Then    'Check if the file exist first before proceeding to unlock
    
        'Rename the file to a temp name
        Dim tempPath As String
        tempPath = Replace(argPath, ".docx", " (Temp).docx")
        Name argPath As tempPath
        
        Dim unlockDoc As Document
        Set unlockDoc = Application.Documents.Open(FileName:=tempPath, PasswordDocument:=strPassword, Visible:=False)
        With unlockDoc
            .Password = noPassword
            .SaveAs FileName:=argPath, Password:=noPassword 'Save back to the original file name
            .Close SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges
        End With
        
        Kill tempPath   'Delete the temp file
        Set unlockDoc = Nothing
    Else
        'Error - File not found
        MsgBox "Error - File not exist: " & vbNewLine & _
                argPath
    End If
End Sub
```